# Sharepoint online thumbnail column issue with missing thumbnailRenderer

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365, sharepoint-online

I actualy have a sharepoint online list with the new column type "thumbnail".

I use the c# graph client to get items, and "AdditionalData" attribut contain columns informations.

exemple:

```json
{
    "fileName":"XXX.png",
    "serverRelativeUrl":"/sites/XXXX/SiteAssets/Lists/XXXX/XXX.png",
    "id":"XXXX",
    "serverUrl":"https://XXXX.sharepoint.com",
    "thumbnailRenderer":
        {
            "spItemUrl":"https://XXXX.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.1/drives/XXXX/items/XXXX",
            "fileVersion":3,
            "sponsorToken":"XXXX"},
            "type":"thumbnail",
            "fieldName":"Img",
            "fieldId":"XXXX"}
        }
}
```

These information is used to get image content, and display it into my application.

```cs
string rawText = itemContent.Fields.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("XXX", out _) ? itemContent.Fields.AdditionalData["XXX"].ToString() : "";
ImageSharepoint ImageContent = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ImageSharepoint>(rawText);               
string[] subs = ImageContent.ThumbnailRenderer.SpItemUrl.Split('/');
int length = subs.Length;
var stream = await graphClient.Drives[subs[length - 3]].Items[length - 1].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

It work fine, but if i change the image for an item, thumbnailRenderer is missing.
On an other list, thumbnailRenderer is always missing.

```cs
{
    "type":"thumbnail",
    "fileName":"XXX.png",
    "nativeFile":{},
    "fieldName":"XXX",
    "serverUrl":"https://XXX.sharepoint.com",
    "fieldId":"XXX",
    "serverRelativeUrl":"/sites/XXX/XXX/SiteAssets/Lists/XXX/XXX.png",
    "id":"XXX"}
}
```

Hown can i be sure to always have this atribute (thumbnailRenderer) properly fill ?

Comment: How do you change the image for an item?

Comment: with sharepoint online interface